# QT QSqlDatabase open() function fails for long database name(database filepath)

Tags: qt, qsqldatabase

QSqlError(-1, "Error opening database", "unable to open database file") when we try to open a qsqldatabase which having long database name(not supported more than 256 bytes)

I tried to remove directory path from database file name and change the current working directory by the above said directory, now file name is small but open call still failed

```
QString dbName = "/home/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789/abc123456789test.db"
QFileInfo fi(dbName);
QDir d = fi.dir();
char buffer[4096];
char* cwd = getcwd(buffer, 4096);
chdir(d.canonicalPath().toStdString().c_str());
m_sqldb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE",connectionName)
m_sqldb.setDatabaseName(fi.fileName());
if(!m_sqldb.isOpen()) {
    ok = m_sqldb.open();
    if (ok) {
    //////
    }
    else {
        qDebug()<<dbName<<m_sqldb.lastError();
        }
}
```

Comment: So it has nothing to do with a long database name? Please minimise your example further, see [mcve].

Comment: No, It is because of long file path only. In open call, internally it takes file name with absolute path.

Comment: Does the full path to the file exist?  I know QSqlDatabase::open() is supposed to create the _file_, but it doesn't seem to if all the folders are not there.